# $\int\frac {dx}{\sqrt{2ax−x²}}=a^n \sin^{-1}(\frac {x}{a}-1)$

Tags: indefinite-integrals

The question is telling us to find n
The options are:
a) 0
b) -1
c) 1
d) none of these
I have tried to solve this by using some general formula of integration yet Iam unable to find the answer

Comment: @A studious student: Can you show the steps of what you have tried?

Comment: The proposed answer are numerical, but the integral is indefinite !?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:$$\sqrt{2ax-x^2} =\sqrt{a^2-(x-a)^2}$$
Also, $$\int\frac {dx}{\sqrt{A^2-x^2}}=\sin^{-1}\frac xA+C$$
Now, can you continue from here?